# Windows 10 browse a phone as WPD?

Tags: windows-10

I have a smartphone  with a problem: it does not charge the battery, so I cannot boot it to Android. I expected to get the files and photos from its internal memory  using a Windows 10 laptop.
I connect the phone to the laptop with a USB cable. The laptop  makes a beep signalling a USB device connected.

the command `pnputil /enum-devices` correctly lists the phone as "LG X view", of the WPD class, but I don't see it under "My computer" in  File explorer, and no new drive letter appears, as it would if I connected an ordinary  USB memory. How can I browse the new WPD's mwmory ? Or list files in it. I am OK with the CLI  or some basic programming (Perl, Python or C) That is, How doI list all available  WPDs and browse them?  The question is about Windows user- level actions, **NOT** about system programming and **NOT** about phones or Android. In my case Android is not even started on the phone, and the phone obviously correctly talks to Windows. This is how Windows shows its status as "Started" and  knows its  characteristics:

- Device Description:         LG X view and
- Manufacturer Name:          LGE and
- Class Name:                 WPD
- Status:                     Started
- Driver Name:                wpdmtp.inf
- Instance ID:                ACPI\ACPI000C\2&daba3ff&1
- Device Description:         ACPI Processor Aggregator
- Class Name:                 System
- Class GUID:                 {4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
  Manufacturer Name:          (Standard system devices)
- Status:                     Started
  Driver Name:                acpipagr.inf
- Instance ID:                SWD\PRINTENUM\PrintQueues

So now the question is how to access a connected and recognized WPD in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Modern access to Android device files requires software running on Android to talk to the PC to transfer the files by PTP or MTP. Without the device booting properly there is nothing for the PC to talk to in order to retrieve files. USB mass storage support, where the Adroid OS is suspended and the device flash is directly accessible as if it were a USB memory stick, was dropped from Android support more than a decade ago.

Most likely all you are seeing is the initial USB controller that automatically returns a device descriptor to the PC so that the PC knows how to request further information from the Android OS.

Because there is no software running on the device it cannot even initialise itself as any kind of storage device.

Even if you could directly read the devices flash from the PC it may not do you any good as [all your files could well be encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264642/are-android-phones-now-encrypted-by-default) and the data you want to retrieve would essentially be random bytes.

You will need to repair the device in order to retrieve the data from it.